# rails 3.2.2, cancan 1.6.7. index fails authorization 1st each session, then is allowed appropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

The plan is for my users to be able to only see other users in users#index if those users belong to the same studio (user.studio_id).

It almost works perfectly.  The only hiccup is... the first time any user (including admin) goes to users/index, they get an unauthorized message.  If they try again, they get the index with only the appropriate records appearing.  How can I make it stop choking on the authorization the first time they go there?

*ability.rb*

```
  class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability


      def initialize(user)
        user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

         can :read, User

        if user.role? :Student
          ...
          cannot :read, User, ["studio_id <> ?", user.studio_id] do |u|
            u.studio_id != user.studio_id
          end
          can :update, User, ["id = ?", user.id] do |u|
            u.id == user.id
          end

        end

        if user.role? :Teacher
          ...
          can :update, User, ["id = ?", user.id] do |u|
            u.id == user.id
          end
        end



        if user.role? :Director
          ...
          can :manage, User, ["studio_id = ?", user.studio_id] do |u|
            u.studio_id == user.studio_id
          end
          can :create, User
        end

        cannot :delete, [Studio, Event]
        cannot :change_studio, [User]

        if user.role? :Admin
          can :manage, :all
          can :see_ids, :all
          can :change_studio, User
        end

      end


    end
  end
```

*UsersController*

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :html, :xml, :json
      load_and_authorize_resource #:only => [:show,:new,:destroy,:edit,:update]

      def index
      end
      ...
    end
```

Comment: double `def initialize(user)` in abiltiy is a copy error?

Comment: yes.. that was a typo putting it in stackoverflow.. thank you for catching that.

Comment: Bah... after checking my real code again.. it wasn't a copy error to stackflow.  I actually had that crap in my code.  Now I feel like an idiot, but thank you very much for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try it the other way around and remove initial `can :read, User` and then allow by `can :read, User, :studio_id => user.studio_id`